# How to load rich:dataTable row data using dynamic rich:column

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I want to show a table using `rich:dataTable`.

I am getting the table but I can't see how to access a list (listTitre) witch contains a list (listeComplements) in the row to show data.

Exemple :

`listeSaisieCmpltsModel.listeComplements` contains

1. Column A
2. Column B
3. Column C

`row.listeComplements` contains

1. Column B data
2. Column C data

the result

- Ref Titre  | A | B | C
- xxxxxxxxx  |   | B | C

I use the code bellow:

```
<rich:dataTable id="idList" value="#{listeSaisieCmpltsModel.listTitre}" var="row">
    <rich:column id="name">
        <f:facet name="header">Ref Titre</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{row.refTitre}" />
    </rich:column>

    <c:forEach items="#{listeSaisieCmpltsModel.listeComplements}" var="column">
        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{column.libelleCoplement}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{row.libelleCoplement.valeur}" />
        </rich:column>
    </c:forEach>
</rich:dataTable>
```

The model :

```
@ManagedBean(name="listeSaisieCmpltsModel")
@SessionScoped
public class ListeSaisieCmpltsModel implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<TitresRechercherComplementsSortieDTO> listTitre;
private List<ComplementsTitresSortieDTO> listeComplements;

public List<TitresRechercherComplementsSortieDTO> getListTitre() {
    return listTitre;
}
public void setListTitre(List<TitresRechercherComplementsSortieDTO> listTitre) {
    this.listTitre = listTitre;
}
public List<ComplementsTitresSortieDTO> getListeComplements() {
    return listeComplements;
}
public void setListeComplements(
        List<ComplementsTitresSortieDTO> listeComplements) {
    this.listeComplements = listeComplements;
}   
}
```

The DTO :

```
public class TitresRechercherComplementsSortieDTO {

    @XmlElement(type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1 .class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected Date datePec;
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected List<ComplementsTitresSortieDTO> listeComplements;
    protected String origineTitre;
    protected String refTitre;

    public Date getDatePec() {
        return datePec;
    }

    public void setDatePec(Date value) {
        this.datePec = value;
    }

    public List<ComplementsTitresSortieDTO> getListeComplements() {
        if (listeComplements == null) {
            listeComplements = new ArrayList<ComplementsTitresSortieDTO>();
        }
        return this.listeComplements;
    }

    public String getOrigineTitre() {
        return origineTitre;
    }


    public void setOrigineTitre(String value) {
        this.origineTitre = value;
    }


    public String getRefTitre() {
        return refTitre;
    }

    public void setRefTitre(String value) {
        this.refTitre = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your content is in the same order example :

`listeSaisieCmpltsModel.listeComplements` contains

1. Column A
2. Column B
3. Column C
   etc

`row.listeComplements` contains

1. Column A data
2. Column B data
3. Column C data
   etc

You can do it using the `c:forEach` `varStatus` :

**View :**

```
<rich:dataTable id="idList" value="#{listeSaisieCmpltsModel.listTitre}" var="row">
    <rich:column id="name">
        <f:facet name="header">Ref Titre</f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="#{row.refTitre}" />
    </rich:column>

    <c:forEach items="#{listeSaisieCmpltsModel.listeComplements}" var="column" varStatus="status">
        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{column.libelleCoplement}" />
            </f:facet>

            <h:inputText value="#{row.listeComplements[status.index].valeur}" />
        </rich:column>
    </c:forEach>
</rich:dataTable>
```

I'm not sure about your exact list getter from your `TitresRechercherComplementsSortieDTO` inside `#{row.listeComplements[status.index].valeur}` indeed.

**Another** option is to modify the DTO to add a method that will return the right data for the right column like this :

**View :**

```
<rich:dataTable id="idList" value="#{listeSaisieCmpltsModel.listTitre}" var="row">
    <rich:column id="name">
        <f:facet name="header">Ref Titre</f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="#{row.refTitre}" />
    </rich:column>

    <c:forEach items="#{listeSaisieCmpltsModel.listeComplements}" var="column" varStatus="status">
        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{column.libelleCoplement}" />
            </f:facet>

            <h:inputText value="#{row.getColumnData(column).valeur}" />
        </rich:column>
    </c:forEach>
</rich:dataTable>
```

**DTO :**

```
public class TitresRechercherComplementsSortieDTO
{
    protected List<ComplementsTitresSortieDTO> listeComplements;

    public ComplementsTitresSortieDTO getColumnData(ComplementsTitresSortieDTO column)
    {
        ComplementsTitresSortieDTO data;

        for(ComplementsTitresSortieDTO dto : getListeComplements())
        {
            if(dto.getCodeComplement() == column.getCodeComplement())
            {
                data = dto;
                break;
            }
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

Since the DTO can't be modified, the function must be moved to the bean like this :

```
public class ListeSaisieCmpltsModel
{
    public ComplementsTitresSortieDTO getColumnData(TitresRechercherComplementsSortieDTO dtoInput, ComplementsTitresSortieDTO column)
    {
        ComplementsTitresSortieDTO data = null;

        for(ComplementsTitresSortieDTO dto : dtoInput.getListeComplements())
        {
            if(dto.getCodeComplement() == column.getCodeComplement())
            {
                data = dto;
                break;
            }
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

And in the view :

```
<h:inputText value="#{listeSaisieCmpltsModel.getColumnData(row,column).valeur}" />
```

Comment: Thank you, did you mean that listeSaisieCmpltsModel.listeComplements and row.listeComplements have the same order ? I edited my post inserting getter and setter.

Comment: For the order, yes exactly, since the example use the index you need the same order between them.

Comment: listeSaisieCmpltsModel.listeComplements contains just the headers to display, and the other one contains all elements

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain but I think we are both understanding :)

Comment: yes I understood you, but my problem is that the two lists are different : list one can contain (A,B,C) and list two (C,D,E) so, I would show the table with columns (A,B,C) and data ( , ,C)

Comment: Yes the content is different but is `row.listeComplements[0]` the right data for `listeSaisieCmpltsModel.listeComplements[0]` ? It will need to, ortherwise you can create a custom method and pass a parameter to get the right data but it will be complicated I think.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30737/discussion-between-alexandre-lavoie-and-netmaster)

Comment: I have a problem with this solution, this DTO is autogenerated by the web service, and I can't edited it. Any suggestion?

Comment: thank you, but `dtoInput.getListeComplements()` doesn't work, `dtoInput` refer to jut one `ComplementsTitresSortieDTO`

Comment: I think I should replace `ComplementsTitresSortieDTO` with `TitresRechercherComplementsSortieDTO` in the arguments

Comment: and another small problem, you should initialize data ^^